# chef definition taking a list of arguments

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

How do I pass a list of attributes to a chef definition?

Below is a code-snippit (not complete). The offending part is indicated with  # ??.

```ruby
define :yum_local_package, :notifies => nil do
  yum_package params[:name] do
    notifies *params[:notifies] # ??
  end
end
```

I expect:

```ruby
yum_local_package my_package do
  notifies :restart, "service[myservice]", :delayed
end
```

to simply forward the "notifies" parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to make it an actual array:

```
yum_local_package my_package do
  notifies [:restart, "service[myservice]", :delayed]
end
```

In related news, you should really use LWRPs for stuff like this as then you don't need any of this tomfoolery with notifications.

Comment: Thanks. I will consider LWRPs later on, but need a quick solution for now.